# How to bind a socket to local wifi network address on Android?

Tags: java, android, sockets

I want to bind a socket to local wifi network address to make sure that requests are not running through 3g or other networks. I tried this code:

```
public static String getIpAddress(WifiManager wifiManager) {
    WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    int ipAddress = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();
    return String.format("%d.%d.%d.%d", (ipAddress & 0xff),(ipAddress >> 8 & 0xff),
            (ipAddress >> 16 & 0xff),(ipAddress >> 24 & 0xff));
}

Socket socket = new Socket();
String localIpAddress = getIpAddress(wifiManager);
socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(localIpAddress, 80));
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(serverHostname, serverPort), (int)   timeoutMs);
```

And it throws:
`java.net.BindException: bind failed: EACCES (Permission denied)`
I checked permissions in Manifest. Looks like all needed permissions are granted:

```
<!-- Uses: show 'disconnected' message when not connected to the internet -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<!-- Uses: record wifi network name when setting up a device -->
<!-- Uses: device wifi setup -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

<!-- Uses: device wifi setup -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot bind to ports below 1024 without superuser access.  So the `Socket.bind()` to port 80 is what is throwing an exception.  Pick a custom port which is above 1024.  For example, most user started web servers use port 8080.